# Use Id for multiple divs and get content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very special problem today using [Spring](https://spring.io/), [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/), Html and JavaScript. I have multiple data sets coming from my Java Backend and for each dataset i have to create a `<div />` and to bind data to hidden divs:

```
<div class="container page-small" th:each="line: ${LINES}">
    <div id="line_data_titles" hidden="true" th:attr="data-txt=${line.titles}"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Using this it would mean that i have a `<div>` with id `line_data_titles` exactly `X` times. There is no way around that. At least nothing is getting in my mind to solve this. So to my question:

If i now use `jQuery` to get the data from my div:

```
<div class="container page-small" th:each="line: ${LINES}">
    <div id="line_data_titles" hidden="true" th:attr="data-txt=${line.titles}"></div>
    ...
    <script>
        var titles = $("#line_data_titles").data("txt");
    </script>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make that `JavaScript` code only valid inside the `<div>` where it is defined so that `jQuery` will only read the value from the `<div>` with the id `line_data_titles` from within the div where it is defined? I hope you understand what i mean. It would look like this:

```
<div class="container page-small">
    <div id="line_data_titles" hidden="true" data-txt="titles of line 0"></div>
    ...
    <script>
        var titles = $("#line_data_titles").data("txt");
    </script>
</div> 

<div class="container page-small">
    <div id="line_data_titles" hidden="true" data-txt="titles of line 1"></div>
    ...
    <script>
        var titles = $("#line_data_titles").data("txt");
    </script>
</div> 

<div class="container page-small">
    <div id="line_data_titles" hidden="true" data-txt="titles of line 2"></div>
    ...
    <script>
        var titles = $("#line_data_titles").data("txt");
    </script>
</div> 

....
```

So i want `jQuery` to only pick the id of the div where the `JavaScript` is defined. Is that possible?

Comment: **`id`** must be **unique**.

Comment: Something like this could be useful to you `<div id="line_data_titles_${LINES}" hidden="true" th:attr="data-txt=${line.titles}"></div>` and   `var titles = $("#line_data_titles_${LINES}").data("txt");`

Comment: `$("#line_data_titles_${LINES}")` is that even possible? If it is i would not need my hidden divs.

Comment: Well I am not sure. I wasn't sure what the notation is used for.

Comment: The Notation comes from Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make that JavaScript code only valid inside the
>    where it is defined so that jQuery will only read the value from
>   the  with the id line_data_titles from within the div where it is
>   defined?

It's not possible, you would have to assign a different id to each element — they have to be unique. Your HTML is not valid if you have more than one element with the same id.

Similar to what "Rejith R Krishnan" said, your problem could likely be solved with dynamic ids, something along the lines of:

```
<div class="container page-small" th:each="line: ${LINES}">
    <div id="line_data_titles_${lines.id}" hidden="true" th:attr="data-txt=${line.titles}"></div> 
    ...
    <script>
        var titles = $("#line_data_titles_${lines.id}").data("txt");
    </script>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use classes, something along the lines of:

```
<div class="container page-small">
  <div class="line_data_titles" hidden="true" data-txt="titles of line 0"></div>
    ...
</div> 

<div class="container page-small">
  <div class="line_data_titles" hidden="true" data-txt="titles of line 1"></div>
    ...
</div>

<script>
  $(".line_data_titles").each(function () {
    var titles = $(this).data("txt");
  })
</script>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: What a pitty. It is not possible to assign different Id's since i dont know how many items i will have and which item jQuery should read.

Comment: you probably want to use a `class` instead then and use it as a selector. You could also use the `data` property for example `data-id` and select it like `$('*[data-id="myId"])`

Comment: @Mulgard see my updated answer, I think that could work for you.

Comment: @m-a-r-c-e-l-i-n-o thx for your help. But how could i get the dynamic ids into jQuery? That is currently the problem. Setting the id's dynamically is easy but how should i know which id to get using jQuery? Usint the annotation ${lines.id} in javascript is not possible.

Comment: Again, lexith's recommendation to use a `class` for this purpose (in addition to the unique `id`s.) A class-selector will quickly locate all candidates-of-interest since any number of DOM elements can be in the same class(es). If you then adopt some kind of predictable standard in creating the `id` strings *(or perhaps, a user-defined attribute ...),* you can identify the element(s) of interest among the `class`-search results. (You can also "take a look at each one's parents," etc.)

Comment: True, thank you very much for your patient help @everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Use class names intead of ids

```
<div class="container page-small">
    <div class="line_data_titles" hidden="true" data-txt="titles of line 0"></div>
</div> 
<div class="container page-small">
    <div class="line_data_titles" hidden="true" data-txt="titles of line 1"></div>
</div> 
<div class="container page-small">
    <div class="line_data_titles" hidden="true" data-txt="titles of line 2"></div>
</div>
```

and jQuery code will be

```
<script>
    var titles = $(".line_data_titles").data("txt"); // for all elements
    var title_1 = $(".line_data_titles")[0].data("txt"); // for the first element
</script>
```

etc...